# Auditing AWS CloudWatch and SNS Notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudWatch Alarm that sends a notification to an SNS topic, and I have a subscriber on that topic setup to receive those notifications.

The problem is, the consumer listening on that topic is *not* receiving the notifications when I see evidence that the alarm *should* be firing notifications to the topic. So I'm trying to figure out:

- Is the alarm not configured properly?
- Is the SNS topic or the subscription on that topic not configured properly?

So I ask: is it possible to get an "*audit*" of when CloudWatch alarms fire notifications? Is it possible to get a similar "audit" in SNS, where you can see a log of what has been published to a particular topic, and whether or not anything successfully consumed/read it?

Comment: Good question - I don't know the answer. What we have done in the past to help debug such situations is to subscribe to the topic with your personal email or phone number. Our situation was an SQS subscriber, and we had to give the topic permission to publish to the queue.

Comment: Ohhh interesting @Rob (+1), what did you end up needing to do to give the topic permission to publish to that SQS queue?

Comment: You might want to ask a question about how to properly subscribe your consumer. If you do that, and the consumer is SQS, comment here with a pointer to the new question and I will tell you what we found in an answer on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have metrics in cloudwatch. When you configure alarms we publish metrics for the same. So you can check in the console if your metric has been published or not. If metric is published that means alarm has been triggered.